# How to remove folder and files in git pack file?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I have a git repository where there are four branches including master. I have created a clone from one branch and deleted the "upload" folder under "wp-content", then pushed the change to git. The push was successful.

The problem is in the git ".pack" file. It stores the history for that folder and files, so when I push my code to AWS it give's git large file error in git history.

Comment: What is the actual problem?  That the folder and files are still there, or that you're getting an error?

Comment: Actually, I had stored all media uploaded files in wordpress upload folder. But now, I have moved all media files to aws S3 Bucket and remove from my git repository branch. 
for now situation is when I try to push my code to aws using aws.push command than it gives large file error. It also give error there is some large file in git history. I have check my .pack file size under git folder it still store my folder path and files. That's why my code not push to aws server

Comment: So the problem is that the files are still appearing in the git pack, correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the files, you are only removing them from the latest commit. Git still has those files stored in the history of the repository, meaning that simply having a commit that removes them won't completely get rid of them.

It is possible to completely remove files from the history of a repository, however you should be very careful when doing this. It will change the commit hashes, and any work based off of commits that get rewritten, like branches, can be difficult to update.

GitHub has a really good help article on completely removing data from a repository here: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/